# share variable outside "for cycle"

Tags: android

By example I need to share the new variable "mess2" to "method1(mess2)":

```
button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) { 
        String numbMess = ediText1.getText().toString();
        int nm=Integer.parseInt(numbMess);    
        String mess = ediText2.getText().toString();
        for(int a=nm; a>0; a--) {
            String mess2 = mess + "\n";
        }
        method1(mess2);
    }
});
```

Comment: I already done by the variable outside is not used

Comment: Please follow some basic Java tutorials before trying to develop apps. This is first day in school stuff.

Comment: I've looked at your question history.  You must be spending hours struggling instead of taking some good advice and **learn first**.  There are several things wrong with your code, but the main one, which you edited in, is declaring a variable inside a loop.  You are not ready to build apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your purpose is to make mess2 a repetition of mess separated with "\n". You can do this:

```
String mess = ediText2.getText().toString();
String mess2 = ""
for(int a = nm; a > 0; a --) {
    mess2 += mess + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Does not run: duplicate local variable

Comment: @PolHallen That's because you have also declared it inside the loop. Please follow some basic Java tutorials before trying to develop apps. This is first day in school stuff.

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo same problem